# Scraping and appending data while looping through html tables

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

I would like to loop through 30 dates of earnings release info in Yahoo Finance while appending each date's info into a singular dataframe. I have used this code but cannot get a consolidated dataframe with all info - it shows info for just the last date:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

date = (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).isoformat() #get tomorrow in iso format as needed'''

for i in range(30):
    try: 
        date = (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days = i )).isoformat() #get tomorrow in iso format as needed'''
        pd.set_option('display.max_column',None)
        url = pd.read_html("https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/earnings?day="+date, header=0)
        table = url[0]
        table.append(table)
        print(table)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your table each iteration. Initialize a list, then append each table into that list. Finaly iterate through thte list of dataframes into 1 dataframe:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

date = (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).isoformat() #get tomorrow in iso format as needed'''

tables = [] #<-- initialize an empty list to store your tables
for i in range(30):
    try: 
        date = (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days = i )).isoformat() #get tomorrow in iso format as needed'''
        pd.set_option('display.max_column',None)
        url = pd.read_html("https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/earnings?day="+date, header=0)
        table = url[0]
        tables.append(table) #<-- apend each table into your list of tables
        print(table)
    except ValueError:
        print ('Error')
        continue


df = pd.concat(tables) #<-- take your list of tables into 1 final dataframe
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list outside loop for saving your tables, then append tables into lst_tables:

```
lst_tables = list()
for i in range(30):
    try: 
        date = (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days = i )).isoformat() #get tomorrow in iso format as needed'''
        pd.set_option('display.max_column',None)
        url = pd.read_html("https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/earnings?day="+date, header=0)
        lst_tables.append(url[0])
        print(url[0]) # if you really need to print it out for checking
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

You can use **pd.concat(lst_tables)** to have a completed dataframe

```
df_completed = pd.concat(lst_tables)
```

Comment: Thanks! I see however that this creates a list with a bunch of dataframes as items living in it as opposed to one dataframe with all data stacked one on top of the other...

Comment: @JuneSmith, Hi I edited answer, you can use pd.concat to have one dataframe with all data stacked